# Cache Firebase Database for offline usage? with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to cache firebase database information for offline usage. In my ProgressiveWebApp, I am using javascript and jquery. Is there a way to mirror database without using polymer
Thank you

Comment: That is possible with the help of the `app-indexeddb-mirror` element. See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#25